# performance of creation to create explosives

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard

Assuming a level 10 creation bard uses *performance of creation* to create a 200gp explosive that is any size up to large. How big would the explosive be, would it be blackpowder-based, and how much damage would it do?

Comment: There is a notable lack of  explosives in the rules (black powder or otherwise), do you have them commonly in your game? If so what rules are they using?

Comment: That's a good question, maybe I should ask if there are raw any nonmagical explosives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a list of possible explosives in the DMG on pages 267-268. Whether they're available in your setting is up to the DM to determine, of course; in standard D&D black powder isn't a thing, so any explosives would be magical in nature and not available to your bard's creation abilities.

Based on the cost limit and prices listed in the table, you'd be able to make a renaissance black powder bomb, but not quite a powder keg.

A black powder bomb can be thrown 60 feet and detonates in a 5-foot-radius area that deals 3d6 fire damage unless the target(s) succeed a DC 12 Dexterity save.

Answer (score 3):

Going by strict rules, the closest thing I can think of that's available for player's to buy and is an explosive would be a flask of Alchemist's Fire. That's 50gp and weighs 1lb.

Making it bigger would probably net you a heavy bottle of Alchemist's Fire, which (scaling linearly) would be 4lb and be worth 200gp. What that does, though, is up to your DM.

Which also brings us to the second part of the answer: if you want an object that's not listed somewhere, you need to ask your DM. It'll probably depend on your setting; if explosives are common and your Bard knows about them, it might work. If explosives in the setting are non-existent, probably a flask of alchemist's fire or a barrel of oil is the best you can hope for.